# Can't compile LAME for iOS

Tags: ios, makefile, lame

I'm trying to compile lame mp3 encoder as static library for iOS. I'd like to support all architectures including i686, armv6, armv7, armv7s and arm64. Here is my build script:

```
#!/bin/bash
DEVELOPER=`xcode-select -print-path`
SDK_VERSION="7.1"
mkdir build
function build_lame()
{
    make distclean
    ./configure \
    CFLAGS="-isysroot ${DEVELOPER}/Platforms/${SDK}.platform/Developer/SDKs/${SDK}${SDK_VERSION}.sdk" \
    CC="${DEVELOPER}/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch ${PLATFORM} -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 " \
    --prefix=/Users/mcrute/Desktop/lame \
    --host="arm-apple-darwin9" \
    --disable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    --disable-decoder \
    --disable-frontend

make -j4
cp "libmp3lame/.libs/libmp3lame.a" "build/libmp3lame-${PLATFORM}.a"
}
SDK="iPhoneSimulator"
PLATFORM="i686"
build_lame
SDK="iPhoneOS"
PLATFORM="armv6"
build_lame
PLATFORM="armv7"
build_lame
PLATFORM="armv7s"
build_lame
PLATFORM="arm64"
build_lame
lipo -create build/* -output build/libmp3lame.a
```

So the error looks like this:

```
configure: error: in `/Users/ivan/Desktop/lame-3.99.5':
configure: error: C preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
cp: libmp3lame/.libs/libmp3lame.a: No such file or directory
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/grjVQZEH) is my *config.log*. | tried to remove arm64 from build targets, but script also failed with same error. Google said that I haven't got gcc but I have.. Looking for any suggestion!

Comment: `/lib/cpp` seems an odd path to me (especially given the path to `clang`) do you know where that value is coming from? Is there a `cpp` binary under `XcodeDefault.xctoolchain` somewhere? Does setting that as the path for `CPP` solve the problem?

Comment: I tried to add env CPP=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cpp. But its still don't work.

Comment: Is that the right path? You added that to the `configure` invocation? Did the error change at all?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I added CPP env var just before executing build script. But nothing happens:( Could you try to build sources from here: http://lame.sourceforge.net with my script?

Comment: So you didn't put it on the `configure` line? With the env var route the error didn't change? Did you `export CPP`? Does putting `CPP=....` on the `configure` line change things? I don't have OS X.

Comment: The problem was solved by adding CPP="***" inside configure, thanks Etan!

Comment: Try this script, if will build LAME as a framework valid for all architectures:  https://github.com/wuqiong/mp3lame-for-iOS

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by adding CPP="***" variable inside configure function. CPP was missed in my env. Edited build script should looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

DEVELOPER=`xcode-select -print-path`

SDK_VERSION="7.1"

mkdir build

function build_lame()
{
    make distclean

    ./configure \
    CPP="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cpp" \
    CFLAGS="-isysroot ${DEVELOPER}/Platforms/${SDK}.platform/Developer/SDKs/${SDK}${SDK_VERSION}.sdk" \
    CC="${DEVELOPER}/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch ${PLATFORM} -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 " \
    --prefix=/Users/ivan/Desktop/lame-3.99.5 \
    --host="arm-apple-darwin9" \
    --disable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    --disable-decoder \
    --disable-frontend

    make -j4
    cp "libmp3lame/.libs/libmp3lame.a" "build/libmp3lame-${PLATFORM}.a"
}

PLATFORM="i686"
SDK="iPhoneSimulator"
build_lame

PLATFORM="armv6"
SDK="iPhoneOS"
build_lame

PLATFORM="armv7"
build_lame

PLATFORM="armv7s"
build_lame

PLATFORM="arm64"
build_lame

lipo -create build/* -output build/libmp3lame.a
```

Comment: Any possibility to make the compiled library public?

Comment: You should be able to build it yourself using that script, as long as you edit `--prefix` to point to your correct lame folder.

Answer (score 0):

From comment to answer.

`CPP` is being set to a very odd value for some reason.

You are manually setting `CC` on the configure line to a path inside `XcodeDefault`.

Try setting `CPP` on the configure call to an appropriate `cpp` binary inside `XcodeDefault` as well.

Comment: In my case, a perfectly normal CPP `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cpp` failed sanity check with Xcode 11.3. Running the same build script in Terminal works fine. What could be wrong? Would you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59350668/c-preprocessor-applications-xcode-app-contents-developer-toolchains-xcodedefau