# C preprocessor "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cpp" fails sanity check

Tags: c++, xcode, makefile, autotools

On macOS Mojave with Xcode 11.3, I have an Autotool based thirdparty lib builds just fine when running my build script in Terminal, but fails when run in Xcode `Run Script` step as `./"$BuildScript"`

```sh
Showing All Messages
/configure:1:1: C preprocessor "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cpp" fails sanity check
```

This seems to correspond to my CPP variable in the script

```
export CPP=$(xcrun --find --sdk "${SDK}" cpp)
```

But I can't figure out why running the script AS IS in Terminal does not have the issue.

Does it have anything to do with Xcode's environment variables?
How should I fix this?

I've tried to switch to different compiler executables to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure you get the same preprocessor executable when you run int Terminal?  The output and / or log file produced by `configure` should tell you what it's using.  Likewise, if you can view the output and log produced when you run inside XCode then that might be illuminating.  Bonus points for comparing one with the other.