# Configure thinks there is a problem with CPP

Tags: c++, linux, c-preprocessor, configure

First off, this is similar to the question here [Can't compile LAME for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25885483/cant-compile-lame-for-ios) but the OP there is apparently dealing with a very different directory structure so the solution there is not relevant to my problem.

I am running configure and getting the error:

```
configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/usr/bin/cpp" fails sanity check
```

I managed to get configure to look at a hopefully more useful cpp with the command

```
./configure CC=mpicc CXX=mpicc CPP=/usr/bin/cpp  CXXCPP=/usr/bin/cpp
```

but it has the same problem with /usr/bin/cpp that it has with /lib/cpp.

I have read somewhere that this means I do not have a `C++` compiler installed, but it is clear that I do (`gcc` and `mpicc`).

Any ideas what the problem is?

BTW, if it matters I am working with `gcc 4.8.5` and `mpich 3.0.x`.

Comment: `gcc` is a C compiler. `g++` is a C++ compiler.

Comment: No idea if this is relevant, but something you should be aware of: GCC4.8.5 is pretty damn old. It doesn't even have complete C++11 support. Current mainline GCC is 10.2

Comment: Configure generates an extensive log file, it will be mentioned in the error message. This contains exactly what configure tried to do (including text of input files). It may contain more clues.